# Country-specific pages same domain or subdomains?

Tags: country-specific, site-structure, localization

On our website, we list businesses such as restaurants. So there are restaurants in USA and say, Mexico. The restaurants in Mexico could be *American* chains as well.

So what's the best way to handle this separation?

**Is there a problem if both live on same domain, just different page name? i.e.**

American Restaurant = `/american-restaurant`

Mexican Restaurant = `/mexican-restaurant`

American Restaurant in Mexico = `/american-restaurant-mx`

**Or should they be separated by directorie**s?

American Restaurant = `/american-restaurant`

Mexican Restaurant = `/mx/mexican-restaurant`

American Restaurant in Mexico = `/mx/american-restaurant-mx`

**Or does it make most sense if other countries are just on a separate subdomain? This means authority and such would not easily pass over from main domain though.**

American Restaurant = `www.domain.com/american-restaurant`

Mexican Restaurant = `mx.domain.com/mexican-restaurant`

American Restaurant in Mexico = `mx.domain.com/american-restaurant-mx`

My favorite is the subdomain idea, but I'm worried about how hard it might be to get it ranked since you basically start with 0 authority all over.

Comment: What is the best way to handle this separation for SEO purposes? Or for UX/UI?

I'd say that the best thing to do is to have all of the places in one website and organize the content in subfolders. This will for example allow you to have breadcrumbs and google (and other SE) will understand how you content is organized. For example : 
Your Website > Countries > States/Regions > Restaurants. 

As a user I think it makes sense to have it like that and this allows you user to go back one level and say, "oh let me look at the restaurants in California"...

Comment: @EdouardF well ideally both. Google does say best UX is best for SEO, even though we know subdomains will most likely be worse for SEO in the short term. I'm just trying to see where people stand and which one is preferable.

Comment: @EdouardF if you used sub directories, would you also translate pages that are aimed at other countries. i.e. `/mx/*` would be in Spanish? To me it seems weird to keep multiple countries/languages on same domain since it means each audience can easily jump to another language/section without much effort.

Comment: I would be saving sub-domains for specific languages and sub-directories for locale. For example, mx.example.com would be Spanish language and /mx/ would be country. To further this, you could use /us/california/san-francisco/ from left to right larger to smaller. You can even include neighborhoods such as /us/washington-dc/nw/adams-morgan. In DC, for example, the city is divided into quarters, nw represents north west, and neighborhoods, such as Adams Morgan which is well known for world cultural activities and restaurants.

Comment: @closetnoc I think using both is ideal if you have content that might need to be in multiple languages for same country because there is a lot of overlapping. For example, Spanish is spoken in Mexico, and the iso code for Spanish is `es`.  So it would have to live on `es.domain.com`. However, there are many Spanish speaking countries, so it would have to be `es.domain.com/es/` for Spain, `es.domain.com/mx/` for Mexico, etc... I was thinking for simplicity's sake to either just stick to sub-directories or sub-domains as I won't need English + Spanish version for Mexican audience.

Comment: Bingo! You are absolutely right. I was not explicit, but that is what I meant.

Comment: I think in my case, since I'm mainly targeting countries, I might just stick with sub directories. i.e. `domain.com/mx`.  This avoids having multiple languages/country combinations and subdomains/sub-directories as it would be hard to manage.